# Unable to Build using MAVEN with ERROR - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.1 descriptor

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

guys. I have been trying to build Hadoop 3.2.1 using maven on Ubuntu (I have tried docker ubuntu/ubuntu 16.04/ubuntu 19.10). But I am stuck with the same error:

My system configurations as shown by maven is followning:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Private Build
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "4.19.76-linuxkit", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Here is my error info:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.1:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project hadoop-maven-plugins: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.1:descriptor failed: syntax error @[1,9] in file:/tmp/hadoop-3.2.1-src/hadoop-maven-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/maven/plugin/protoc/._ProtocTestMojo.java -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.1:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project hadoop-maven-plugins: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.1:descriptor failed: syntax error @[1,9] in file:/tmp/hadoop-3.2.1-src/hadoop-maven-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/maven/plugin/protoc/._ProtocTestMojo.java
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.1:descriptor failed: syntax error @[1,9] in file:/tmp/hadoop-3.2.1-src/hadoop-maven-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/maven/plugin/protoc/._ProtocTestMojo.java
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
```

Here is my pom.xml (I didn't change anything, it's default version):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-main</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <description>Apache Hadoop Main</description>
  <name>Apache Hadoop Main</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cenqua.clover</groupId>
        <artifactId>clover</artifactId>
        <!-- Use the version needed by maven-clover-plugin -->
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>${distMgmtStagingId}</id>
      <name>${distMgmtStagingName}</name>
      <url>${distMgmtStagingUrl}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>${distMgmtSnapshotsId}</id>
      <name>${distMgmtSnapshotsName}</name>
      <url>${distMgmtSnapshotsUrl}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <site>
      <id>apache.website</id>
      <url>scpexe://people.apache.org/www/hadoop.apache.org/docs/r${project.version}</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>${distMgmtSnapshotsId}</id>
      <name>${distMgmtSnapshotsName}</name>
      <url>${distMgmtSnapshotsUrl}</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <organization>
    <name>Apache Software Foundation</name>
    <url>https://www.apache.org</url>
  </organization>

  <properties>
     <hadoop.version>3.2.1</hadoop.version>
    <!-- platform encoding override -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- maven plugin versions -->
    <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.8.1</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
    <maven-site-plugin.version>3.6</maven-site-plugin.version>
    <maven-stylus-skin.version>1.5</maven-stylus-skin.version>
    <maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.7</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
    <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.0.0-M1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <maven-gpg-plugin.version>1.5</maven-gpg-plugin.version>
    <maven-remote-resources-plugin.version>1.5</maven-remote-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <apache-rat-plugin.version>0.12</apache-rat-plugin.version>
    <wagon-ssh.version>2.4</wagon-ssh.version>
    <maven-clover2-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-clover2-plugin.version>
    <maven-bundle-plugin.version>2.5.0</maven-bundle-plugin.version>
    <lifecycle-mapping.version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <checkstyle.version>8.19</checkstyle.version>
    <dependency-check-maven.version>1.4.3</dependency-check-maven.version>

    <shell-executable>bash</shell-executable>

  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <rules>
              <requireMavenVersion>
                <version>[3.0.2,)</version>
              </requireMavenVersion>
              <requireJavaVersion>
                <version>[1.8,)</version>
              </requireJavaVersion>
            </rules>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${apache-rat-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-site-plugin.version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency><!-- add support for ssh/scp -->
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
              <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
              <version>${wagon-ssh.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
              <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
              <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only.
        It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>${lifecycle-mapping.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.2,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>testResources</goal>
                      <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.5.3,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>schema</goal>
                      <goal>protocol</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.0-alpha-3,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                      <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.2,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.3.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-clover2-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
              <artifactId>hadoop-build-tools</artifactId>
              <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <configLocation>checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle/suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
            <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
            <format>xml</format>
            <format>html</format>
            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/test/checkstyle-errors.xml</outputFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
          <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
          <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>clean</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>site</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-property</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireProperty>
                  <property>hadoop.version</property>
                  <message>You must set a hadoop.version to be the same as ${project.version}</message>
                  <regex>${project.version}</regex>
                  <regexMessage>The hadoop.version property should be set and should be ${project.version}.</regexMessage>
                </requireProperty>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>.gitattributes</exclude>
            <exclude>.gitignore</exclude>
            <exclude>.git/**</exclude>
            <exclude>.idea/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/build/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/patchprocess/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.js</exclude>
         </excludes>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- OWASP's dependency-check plugin will scan the third party
             dependencies of this project for known CVEs (security
             vulnerabilities against them). It will produce a report
             in target/dependency-check-report.html. To invoke, run
             'mvn dependency-check:aggregate'. Note that this plugin
             requires maven 3.1.1 or greater.
        -->
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <configuration>
              <maxmemory>1024m</maxmemory>
              <quiet>true</quiet>
              <verbose>false</verbose>
              <source>${maven.compile.source}</source>
              <charset>${maven.compile.encoding}</charset>
              <reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</reportOutputDirectory>
              <destDir>hadoop-project/api</destDir>
              <excludePackageNames>org.apache.hadoop.authentication*,org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server*,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp*</excludePackageNames>
              <groups>
                <group>
                  <title>Common</title>
                  <packages>org.apache.hadoop*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>HDFS</title>
                  <packages>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>MapReduce</title>
                  <packages>org.apache.hadoop.mapred*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>YARN</title>
                  <packages>org.apache.hadoop.yarn*</packages>
                </group>
              </groups>
              <doclet>org.apache.hadoop.classification.tools.IncludePublicAnnotationsStandardDoclet</doclet>
              <docletArtifacts>
                <docletArtifact>
                  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                </docletArtifact>
              </docletArtifacts>
              <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>

              <!-- switch on dependency-driven aggregation -->
              <includeDependencySources>false</includeDependencySources>

              <dependencySourceIncludes>
                <!-- include ONLY dependencies I control -->
                <dependencySourceInclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations</dependencySourceInclude>
              </dependencySourceIncludes>

            </configuration>
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>analyze-report</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>src</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>src-dist</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                  <attach>false</attach>
                  <finalName>hadoop-${project.version}-src</finalName>
                  <outputDirectory>hadoop-dist/target</outputDirectory>
                   <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>hadoop-assemblies/src/main/resources/assemblies/hadoop-src.xml</descriptor>
                  </descriptors>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>src-dist-msg</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <target>
                    <echo/>
                    <echo>Hadoop source tar available at: ${basedir}/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-${project.version}-src.tar.gz</echo>
                    <echo/>
                  </target>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    ......
    <profile>
      <id>clover</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>clover</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <cloverLicenseLocation>${user.home}/.clover.license</cloverLicenseLocation>
        <cloverDatabase>${project.build.directory}/clover/hadoop-coverage.db</cloverDatabase>
           <cloverAlwaysReport>true</cloverAlwaysReport>
        <cloverGenHtml>true</cloverGenHtml>
        <cloverGenXml>true</cloverGenXml>
        <cloverGenHistorical>false</cloverGenHistorical>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              ......
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/examples/**/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/hamlet/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/ha/proto/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/protocol/proto/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/compiler/generated/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/protobuf/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/v2/proto/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/yarn/proto/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/security/proto/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/tools/proto/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/hs/proto/*.java</exclude>
         ......
</project>
```

Due to word limit, [here is the complete pom.xml][1]:https://github.com/xyfuestc/ECHadoop/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Could you please show what `/tmp/hadoop-3.2.1-src/hadoop-maven-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/maven/plugin/protoc/._ProtocTestMojo.java` contains?

Comment: @MikhailKopylov, [link]here is the info about ProtoTestMojo.java(https://github.com/xyfuestc/ECHadoop), thanks in advance.